# Issue with max-width and the relative sizes of elements across devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an issue with a media query. Using the following HTML and CSS, the b-class element is supposed to narrow to 128px when the window narrows to the point it would otherwise overlap with the a-class element (roughly). This works on my 3000x2000 laptop display, but in Firefox on my mobile in landscape mode, the elements overlap without the media query rule kicking in.

Example code: [codepen.io/krainert/pen/KKzVQLP](https://codepen.io/krainert/pen/KKzVQLP)`code below`

```
<p class="a">Here is a headline</p>
<p class="b">Here is a nav element with several menu items</p>

body, p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'calibri';
}
.a {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 832px) {
    .b {
        width: 128px;
    }
}
```

I reckon this is caused by discrepancies between differences in device-width and the screen-relative sizes of elements across devices -- that is to say, the difference between device-width on mobile to that on my laptop is greater than the difference between the widths of the elements on mobile to those on my laptop relative to the sizes of their screens. Or maybe I'm confusing myself. What's the best way to fix it?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets in the question itself.

Comment: Is the issue due to font size difference on the devices? Is the red text sitting over the blue text and you cannot read the blue text? Maybe add 128px of padding to the right of the blue text in the media query so it stops at the text and doesn't overlap it.

Comment: Code added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting the width of the .a container, so they don't overlap:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 832px) {
    .b {
        width: 128px;
    }
    .a {
        width: calc(100vw - 128px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! While this works on my laptop, the problem is unaffected in Firefox on Android.